# HTTP Status 404 - Servlet mvc-dispatcher is not available jars already added in user library being used

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Getting an error even after adding all jars in user library HTTP Status 404 - Servlet mvc-dispatcher is not available jars already added in user library being used. Tried all sorts not able to resolve Can't post screenshots as i don't have 10 points

Servlet mapping code in web.xml is below:

```
    <servlet>
     <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.class</servlet-class>
     <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
     </servlet>

     <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>*.spring</url-pattern>
     </servlet-mapping>
```

My Jsp is below

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form action="Login.spring" method = "post">
    <input type = "text" name = "userName" id = "userName">
    <input type = "password" name = "password" id = "password">
    <input type = "submit">
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My Controller is below
        package com.lnt.controller;

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    import com.lnt.services.AuthenticateServices;

    @Controller 
    @RequestMapping("/Login.spring")
    public class LoginController {

        //@Autowired
         AuthenticateServices authenticateService = new AuthenticateServices();

        @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public ModelAndView processCredentials(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)

        {
            String userName =req.getParameter("userName") ;
            String password = req.getParameter("password");
            System.out.println("into login controller");
            String message = "Invalid credentials";
            List<String> userdetails = new ArrayList<String>();
            userdetails = authenticateService.verifyUserNameAndPassword(userName, password);
            if((userdetails)!=null)
                {
                message = "welcome" + userName ;
            }
            return new ModelAndView("results", "message", message) ;
        }



        }
```

Here is the stack trace :

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.class
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1095)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)

Comment: Isn't there any one who can help?

Comment: Don't post screenshots. Your question is extremely vague. Post relevant code, post relevant configuration. Post expected output. Post actual output.

Comment: I have never faced this error earlier This is due to missing jar files even after i have added spring mvc webservlet jar which contains servlet dispatcher class.

I am trying make a login application using spring MVC using spring and hibernate

Comment: <servlet>
 <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.class</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.spring</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Edit your question. It is hard to read code in comments.

Comment: This is my web.xml configuration

Comment: I am extremely sorry i can only post in comments and can't reply on my on Questions as i have lss repo points.

Comment: Look at your question. There is a small `edit` button. Click it and edit the content of your question.

Comment: Thanks Arjun checking those links.

Comment: Sotrios ..just edited it and posted. @arjun it was working fine earlier as i have same controller mapping in controller. I agree that a bad code practice just got this as a sample application

Comment: But Still why DISPATCHER SERVLET is not avaialable? it is goveng class not found error just edited please check the stacktrace.

Comment: Hello Guyz.? Arjun your links are not helpful as they are using maven but i am not. Additionaly i have all jars required in my user library which i am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration is wrong

```
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.class</servlet-class>
```

The `<servlet-class>` element expects the name of a class. There is no such class called

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.class
```

You probably meant

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
```

Comment: Its giving error. Even after changing the class name and removing .class from name and building and cleaning.

Comment: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)

Comment: i copied qualified classname from jar files in class

Comment: @user2152452 Then you haven't added the jars to where they should be. They should be in `WEB-INF/libs` in the generated WAR.